# Show that the eigenvectors of $T$ generate a subspace of $C ^ {2}$ of dimension 1.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ an operator on $C ^ {2}$given by
$T (x_ {1}, x_ {2}) = (2x_ {1}-x_ {2}, x_ {1})$.

Show that the eigenvectors of $T$ generate a subspace of $C ^ {2}$ of dimension 1.

I did this:

Applying

$f(x)=det(A-xI)=x^2-2x+1$ then the eugenvalues are $c_1=c_2=1$

I got (1,1) and (1,1) for the eigenvectors, 
the space generated by the eigenvectors is of the form $(a, a)$ with $a \in{}\mathbb{C}$     ,clearly this is a "line" then the subspace have one dimension

How can I  conclude this last part?

Thanks for your help and sorry for any inconvenience

Have a nice day :D

Comment: The zero vector is **never** an eigenvector.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry I wrote incorrectly, Thanks for your help :D, always help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that the space is one-dimensional, exhibit a basis with only one element. $(1,1)$ should work.